# Wie heißt die Langform der Abkürzung "Co"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, abbreviation

Ich habe gerade diese Abkürzung in einem Satz gefunden und leider nicht verstanden. Wikipedia und andere Internetseiten waren auch nicht besonders hilfreich.

Der Satz lautet: *Die Handfläche aus hochwertigem Ziegenleder sorgt für besten Grip und macht so das Handling von Skistock, Brille und **Co** einfach.*

Der Satz kommt aus der Produktbeschreibung von Skihandschuhen.

Comment: Naja, das hat aber in diesem Fall keinen Sinn.

Comment: schon gecheckt Duden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Co_Compagnie_Kompanie oder http://www.duden.de/Shop/Duden-Das-W%C3%B6rterbuch-der-Abk%C3%BCrzungen ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Co oder Co. ist die Abkürzung von **Compagnie**. Im zugehörigen [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compagnie) ist beschrieben, dass dieser Namenszusatz ursprünglich bei Firmennamen dazu diente, darauf hinzuweisen, dass es noch mehrere Gesellschafter gibt.

Im übertragenen Sinn und der Umgangssprache wird die Abkürzung dafür verwendet, auf eine Gruppe hinzuweisen, deren "Kopf" bekannt ist, die anderen Identitäten aber unbekannt und unscharf sind. In dem Beispiel "Skistock, Brille und Co" ist dabei weiteres Zubehör beim Skifahren gemeint, das mit den Handschuhen gut angefasst und genutzt werden kann. Also zum Beispiel Skistiefel, Skipass usw.

Comment: Dieser Namenszusatz wurde nicht nur ursprünglich, sondern wird auch heute noch verwendet, um mehrere Gesellschafter anzuzeigen, klassisch auch in der Konstruktion der _GmbH & Co. KG_

Comment: Darüberhinaus kommt es auch den den titeln der diversen Zoo-Sendungen der ARD vor: Elefant, Tiger & Co, Panda, Gorilla & Co,..

Comment: Also es handelt sich bei *und Co* um denselben Sachverhalt, der auch mit *u. s. w.* und *etc.* abgekürzt wird; beide sind weniger salopp und damit universeller.